# "Controller method not found." em um método que existe

Tags: laravel

Estou iniciando com o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) e em um projeto que já estava em andamento.
Estou tentando acessar a url http://mydomain.com.br/purchases/edit/1 e está sempre retornando.

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
>   Controller method not found.

Sendo que no controller possui estes dois métodos:

```
public function getEdit($id) {
    //
    try {
        $record = Purchase::whereId($id)->first();
        $record->status = ($record->status === 'PENDENTE') ? 'ENTREGUE' : 'PENDENTE';
        $record->save();
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
        return Redirect::to('purchases')->with('errors', new MessageBag(array(
            "An item with the ID:$id could not be found."
        )));
    }

    return Redirect::to('purchases')->with('success', new MessageBag(array(
        'Item Atualizado'
    )));

}

public function postEdit($id) {
    //
    $record = Product::whereId($id)->first();
    $record->fill(Input::all());

    $record->save();
    return Redirect::to('products')->with('success', new MessageBag(array(
        'Item Atualizado'
    )));
}
```

e existe este form na *view* edit:

```
@extends('laravel-bootstrap::layouts.interface-edit')

@section('title')
    Editar Usuário: {{ $item->name }}
@stop

@section('heading')
    <h1>Editar Usuário: <small>{{ $item->name }}</small></h1>
@stop

@section('form-items')

      {{-- The title form item --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label( "title" , 'Título' , array( 'class'=>'col-lg-2 control-label' ) ) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text( "title" , Input::old( "title", $item->title ) , array( 'class'=>'form-control' , 'placeholder'=>'Título' ) ) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- The content form item --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label( "content" , 'Conteúdo' , array( 'class'=>'col-lg-2 control-label' ) ) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text( "content" , Input::old( "content", $item->content ) , array( 'class'=>'form-control' , 'placeholder'=>'Conteúdo' ) ) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- The points form item --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label( "points" , 'Pontos' , array( 'class'=>'col-lg-2 control-label' ) ) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text( "points" , Input::old( "points", $item->points ) , array( 'class'=>'form-control' , 'placeholder'=>'Pontos' ) ) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- The image form item --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label( "image" , 'Imagem' , array( 'class'=>'col-lg-2 control-label' ) ) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{ Form::text( "image" , Input::old( "image", $item->image ) , array( 'class'=>'form-control' , 'placeholder'=>'Imagem' ) ) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- The status form item --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label( "ststus" , 'Status' , array( 'class'=>'col-lg-2 control-label' ) ) }}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <label class="radio">
                {{ Form::radio( "status" , true, $item->status) }} SIM 
            </label>
            <label class="radio">
                {{ Form::radio( "status" , false, !$item->status) }} NÃO
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

E estar Rotas

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'AuthController@doLogout');
Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthController@doLogin');
Route::post('auth/recuperar', 'AuthController@doRecuperar');
Route::get('admin', 'AuthController@doAdmin');
Route::post('/auth/admin/login', 'AuthController@doLoginAdmin');


// Route::controller( 'admin/products'  , 'ProductsController' );

Route::controller('users', 'UsersController', array('before' => 'adminauth'));
Route::controller('products', 'ProductsController', array('before' => 'adminauth'));
Route::controller('purchases/{sort?}', 'PurchasesController', array('before' => 'adminauth'));
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

Comment: Pode postar as rotas da sua aplicação?

Comment: Rotas adicionadas

Comment: O meu palpite é que você só colocou o nome da classe na rota – tem que colocar o FQDN lá, que é o nome da classe mais o namespace.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nisso, como eu disse é o primeiro contato com Laravel e é pra resolver este problema. HEHE

Comment: Inseri a rota `Route::get('purchases/edit{id}', 'PurchasesController@getEdit');` mas não surtiu efeito nenhum

Comment: Faltou uma barra em `purchases/edit{id}`, que seria `purchases/edit/{id}`. Você pode ver as rotas configuradas na aplicação com o comando `php artisan routes`.

Comment: Corrigi e funfou, vou postar a solução como resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltava definir a rota para este action em /app/controllers/route.php

```
Route::get('purchases/edit/{id}', 'PurchasesController@getEdit');
```

Com a inclusão desta linha o erro foi corrigido e a funcionalidade está perfeita.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia declarar a rota desta forma:

```
Route::controller('purchases', 'PurchasesController');
```

e no seu controller coloca os filtros no método construtor.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('adminauth');
}
```

Desta forma as rotas getEdit, postEdit e demais adicionadas posteriormente no controller responderiam.